How can types from supabase-js be used generically?
I am trying to write a helper function for some common queries I need to make to my supabase db in my typescript app. So far, I have two functions, findOne and findAll. I'm running into an issue though, where code that works for findOne seems to break for findAll. This code compiles properly:
export async function findOne<
    T extends TableName,
    C extends string & keyof RowType<T>,
>(
    db: SupabaseClient<Database>,
    table: T,
    column: C,
    value: NonNullable<ColumnType<T, C>>,
): Promise<RowType<T> | null> {
    const response: PostgrestSingleResponse<RowType<T> | null> = await db
        .from<T, Table<T>>(table)
        .select()
        .eq(column, value)
        .maybeSingle();
    if (response.error) {
        throw response.error;
    }
    if (!response.data) {
        return null;
    }
    return response.data;
}

but using this for findAll gives an error:
export async function findAll<
    T extends TableName,
    C extends string & keyof RowType<T>,
>(
    db: SupabaseClient<Database>,
    table: T,
    column: C,
    value: NonNullable<ColumnType<T, C>>,
): Promise<RowType<T>[]> {
    const response: PostgrestResponse<RowType<T>> = await db
        .from<T, Table<T>>(table)
        .select()
        .eq(column, value);
    if (response.error) {
        throw response.error;
    }
    return response.data;
}

The error message is as follows: Error:Type 'PostgrestSingleResponse<(Table<T>["Row"] extends SelectQueryError<infer E extends string> ? SelectQueryError<E> : { [K in keyof Table<T>["Row"]]: Table<...>["Row"][K]; })[]>' is not assignable to type 'PostgrestResponse<RowType<T>>'.
My utility types are included here:
type TableName = keyof Database["public"]["Tables"];
type Table<T extends TableName> = Database["public"]["Tables"][T];
type RowType<T extends TableName> = Database["public"]["Tables"][T]["Row"];
type ColumnType<
    T extends TableName,
    Column extends keyof RowType<T>,
> = RowType<T>[Column];

I've tried adding and removing more specific typing on the findAll function to no avail. No matter how I adjust the type definitions, the error remains as the above. It looks to me like the type system is having trouble with specificity to rule out a SelectQueryError.

I am having the same issue. For what I read that typing comes from postgress and in your returned data you have to first type is as "unkown" then type it as your RowType.
Example:  return data as unknown as RowType<T>.
Then hover on Data and you will see that data has a type from postgress you have to remove first... Weird I know.
